# Backup files very different size

Tags: 9, backups

for a Drupal website, backup is done via databack/mysql-backup (https://hub.docker.com/r/databack/mysql-backup) container.
Drupal version: 9.5.10.
The backup is created.
The created backup file is uploaded to AWS, which works objection free.
But, as visible on the picture, the backup files have very different size!

Does anyone have any idea why the backup files have such different size?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real way to know why they are different sizes is to decompress the files and compare them.

If the backups all restore correctly, the difference is that you are probably backing up the cache tables in the larger files.

Instead of using a generic MySQL backup solution, I would use Drush and the [drush sql:dump command](https://www.drush.org/12.x/commands/sql_dump/), which can be used to [exclude the cache tables.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/175550/how-to-skip-specific-tables-with-drush-sql-dump)

An alternative is to use the [Backup and Migrate module.](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate)

Comment: Hi,
thank you very much for your answer.
I have solved the backup problem via a shell script.